# Uso de comprehensions en matrices

Tags: python, matrices

Indagando y estudiando un poco, he estado intentando hacer muchos ejercicios de matrices con comprehensions, pero hay uno que se me está resistiendo:
En este caso me da un problemita que dice que dada una lista de listas que tiene números, que cree una nueva lista de listas que a los números pares les asigne la letra del abecedario que les corresponde y a los impares un guion.

sin comprehensions es bastante sencillo, pero demasiado largo:

```
def num_letras(matriz_num):
    lista1=[]
    lista2=[]
    str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in matriz_num:
        for j in i:
            if j % 2 == 0:
                lista1.append(str[j])
            else:
                lista1.append("-")
        lista2.append(lista1)
        lista1=[]
    return lista2


lista_original =  [[2, 4, 1], [3, 5, 2], [6, 7, 1]]

print(num_letras(lista_original))
```

Yo ya he hecho comprehensions con alguna condición, pero sin ningún else (por ejemplo:[[j for j in i if j >= numero] for i in matriz]) pero este al tener un else, me esta siendo muy difícil compaginar las comprehensions.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda y explicación si no es mucha molestia!!!
Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto tiene solución sencilla si, además de compresiones de listas, usas una expresión condicional.

La expresión condicional se parece superficialmente a una sentencia condicional (pues usa también las palabras reservadas `if`, `else`), pero no es una sentencia sino una expresión. Por tanto puede ponerse en cualquier lugar donde python admita una expresión, como por ejemplo en una comprensión de listas.

La sintaxis general de la expresión condicional es:

```
valor1 if condicion else valor2
```

El resultado de evaluar esa expresión es `valor1` si `condicion` era cierta, o bien `valor2` en caso contrario. Ese resultado se puede por ejemplo asignar a una variable:

```
r = valor1 if condicion else valor2
```

o se puede usar dentro de una comprensión de listas.

En tu caso, la solución sería:

```
letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
lista_original =  [[2, 4, 1], [3, 5, 2], [6, 7, 1]]

print( [ [letras[i] if i%2==0 else "-" for i in sublista] for sublista in lista_original ] )
```

Resultado:

```
[['c', 'e', '-'], ['-', '-', 'c'], ['g', '-', '-']]
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! No conocia las expresiones condicionales y ahora creo que puedo incluso simplificar muchos ejercicios!!!!